# How to take multiple values in textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to take the language known by a user. A person can know multiple languages. I want that when a user press "E" then the languages that have "E" as their starting letter are displayed below textbox and user is forced to select the value from the displayed values and secondly I want to take multiple languages.

This is just like when question is asked on stackoverflow.com while selecting the tags.

Comment: Saying that a question is urgent is unlikely to get you a faster response. Instead you should try to improve your question, then people can help you faster. Why is your question tagged SQL? Is the list of available languages stored in a database?

Comment: Your question is vague, and does not provide enough information to help you with your problem.  If your problem is really urgent, then clearly explaining yourself will help you get it answered faster than pleading.

Answer (score 1):

Rough first answer: look at the Ajax Control Toolkit:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

You want to use the AutoCompleteExtender. There are really good samples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax or jQuery will help you in this issue not sql